# Beamer presentation. Changing the color theme

Tags: beamer, color, themes

Please consider this document.

https://da.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations/thomas-jansson-ku-style-beamer

**How do I change the theme from Green to Red?**

Dark green = dark red, light green = light red

I have tried to change

```
\definecolor{kugreen}{RGB}{50,93,61}
\definecolor{kugreenlys}{RGB}{132,158,139}
\definecolor{kugreenlyslys}{RGB}{173,190,177}
\definecolor{kugreenlyslyslys}{RGB}{214,223,216}
```

Using the information I get from
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors

but the results are not satisfying. Maybe I should change my theme which is PaloAlto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the color through the command

```
\usecolortheme[named=kugreen]{structure}
```

So just define a suitable red base color (I used the dark red from the KU logo on your presentation) and use that instead of `kugreen` for the color theme.

```
\definecolor{kured}{RGB}{133,37,36}
\usecolortheme[named=kured]{structure}
```

The lighter colors will automatically be deferred from the base color for the structure.

For the sake of completeness and so that other will be able to reproduce the problem, here is the relevant part of your document as a working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}[10]
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\definecolor{kured}{RGB}{133,37,36}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme[numbers,totalnumber,compress,sidebarshades]{PaloAlto}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usecolortheme[named=kured]{structure}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

%\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.8cm]{KULogo}}
\title{Sample Title}
\author{Thomas R. N. Jansson}
\institute{Niels Bohr Institute \\ University of Copenhagen}
\date{6 June 2014}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage \vspace{-0.5cm}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx. Problem Solved. Totally different question: How can I add a red line/thin box on the BUTTOM of my pages with the text in every slide? The same text

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your solutions. I found them very helpful!!